# Add custom UI Component (button) to product listing with POST request

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

how can I add button that make POST request to controller next to "Add Product" button in product listing? So far I do it like this, but it isn't send POST:

Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <settings>
            <buttons>
                <button name="synchronize" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\CustomButton">
                </button>
            </buttons>
        </settings>
    </listing>
```

Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/CustomButton

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class CustomButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    private $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(UrlInterface $urlBuilder)
    {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label'=>__('Custom label'),
            'class' => 'action-secondary',
            'on_click'=> "setLocation('" .
                $this->urlBuilder->getUrl("path/to/controller", ['key'=>$this->urlBuilder->getSecretKey('front', 'controller', 'action')])
                . "')",
            'sort_order'=>100,
            
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a post request, you need a request body (data to send along with the POST) and the UI doesn't provide body property, so it's understandable that you cannot send POST within the current implementation.